# Loading an Android Resource into a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an Android app that displays a comic book. To make use of the built-in zoom controls, I am loading the pictures in a [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) like so:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page1.jpg");
```

This is working just fine, however, since the images are in the assets folder, they are not being compressed which makes my *.apk* enormous. I was wondering how to reference resource files (from the `res/drawable` folder) with a file path like I did above with the assets. Does anyone know what that path would look like? I've tried things like `"file:///res/drawable/pagetitle.jpg"` with no success. Thanks for the help.

---

**Update:**

I found that `"file:///android_res/drawable/page1.jpg"` was the path that I was looking for.

Comment: I dont think that there is any other direct way. But u can try using [loadData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: I just don't get your idea of further compressing jpg images. They're already compressed! Also, images in res folder are also not being compressed by Android build tools, because the tools are clever and avoid compressing jpg/png images twice, which makes no sense.

Comment: @PointerNull PNG recompression can make a lot of sense, see http://addyosmani.com/blog/image-optimization-tools/ - recompressing lossy JPG again is to be avoided under all circumstances unless one considers the artefacts as modern art...

Comment: @Philzen: we're talking about ZIP compression of JPG or PNG, which is useless because zipped JPG or PNG is of same size (+-1%) as original. Your article discusses something else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

from [this site](http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html)

Using the resource id, the format is:

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/" + R.raw.myvideo);
```

or, using the resource subdirectory (type) and resource name (filename without extension), the format is:

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]"

Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/raw/myvideo");
```

Comment: I found a different solution (see the update) and I haven't tried this, but thank you for the response.

Comment: Using `android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/" + R.raw.myvideo` with `webView.loadUrl` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: use `file:///android_res/raw/myvideo.mp4` for webview.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, yet I'm unable to see how it answers the question. The question asked "how to reference resource files ... with a file path", but this answer gives a non-`file` `Uri`. The question asks about loading a resource, and shows the use of `webView.loadUrl(String)`, but this answer doesn't tell how to load a resource, and a `Uri` can't be passed directly to `loadUrl()`.

Answer (score 6):

I also had to use `loadDataWithBaseURL` instead of just plain `loadData` to get the `file:///android_res/drawable/page1.jpg` to work.

Comment: would this leverage other qualifiers as -xhdpi etc. ?