# Android: how to retrieve an image from res/drawable and put it into WebView.loadUrl()

Tags: java, android

I already tried the following but without success.
My project is using API level 4.

[from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855008/loading-an-android-resource-into-a-webview)

[from android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openAssetFileDescriptor%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29)

Here is my code:

```
webView.loadUrl("android.resource://com.package.name.from.manifest/" + R.drawable.pic);
```

And I've got the following error in the WebView widget:

> Web page not available
>
> The Web page at
>   android.resource://com.package.name.from.manifest/2130837504 might be
>   temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
>   address.

Am I missing something? Should I create html page which will include a link to the resource as < img ...> tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I have done the following:

I had an array of file name extensions of each of the image in resources.
And then I could call the following method with the resource ID and it's file name extension.

```
protected String getResourceURL(int resourceId, String extension) {
    String resName = getResources().getResourceName(resourceId);
    int index = resName.indexOf("/");
    resName = resName.substring(0, index);
    index = resName.indexOf(":");
    String resType = resName.substring(index + 1);

    StringBuilder link = new StringBuilder(128);
    link.append("file:///android_res/");
    link.append(resType).append("/");
    link.append(getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId));
    link.append(".").append(extension);
    return link.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get image path like this.

file:///android_res/drawable/YOUR_FILE_NAME

Pass this path to  tag in html.It will work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should have your drawables in assets/ folder, then refer to them through a URI in the form of `file:///android_asset/drawable_name.png`, for example.

Comment: This will probably work, but I don't want to retrieve file, since files can be different extension, but same name. For example: in several times the file can be 01.png, on other can be 01.jpg

Comment: Which means, that I need a link which will directly retrieve resource by resource id and not the file name

Answer (score -3):

I hope it is helpfull..
For getting image from res/drawable..

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. WebView.loadUrl(String url). How can I receive link from Drawable?