# How to access an image in the drawable folder from within an HTML file in the assets folder?

Tags: android, css, xml, drawable, android-assets

I am using an XML file to display an "About" page in my app. This xml file is in the assets folder and is displayed using a WebView layout.

I want to use css to set a background image for this xml file. The image is in the drawable-mdpi folder. Is there a way that I can access that image?

What I mean is something like this? (or an alternative, ofcourse)

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-image:url('path-to-image-in-drawable-mdpi');
}
//...
</style>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading an Android resource into a webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855008/loading-an-android-resource-into-a-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you write

```
<script type="text/css">
body{background-image:url('file:///android_res/drawable/file_name.jpg');}
</script>
```

Comment: This won't always work on a production apk. In my case it worked on a debug apk, but it results in a broken image when testing the obfuscated and signed apk.