# Can not acess url that are present in the html files from Webview in Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to access the url using the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. For some reason when I try to access the url that are present in the html files, I get Web page not available error.Previously I could access the url because I stored my html file in the raw folder but I needed to move it to assets folder as the code looks cleaner this way. This is my code, could anyone let me know how I can resolve this.

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile/file.html");
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("some text")){
            setDialog("some fancy text");
        }
```

Comment: why are you calling setWebViewClient() twice? also is your html file in a subfolder or directly in the assets folder?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I honestly missed that, however yeah the file is in a subfolder in the assets folder..

Comment: what does it show instead of of the web page? is there any message in the logcat when loadUrl call happens?

Comment: Sorry Tim but there is no message in the logcat, when I try to access the url, a web page not available page is displayed with the error..web page at file:///android_asset/File/sometext could not be loaded as the requested file was not found..

Comment: try moving it out of the subfolder, so it will be directly in the assets folder. I don't know why that would help but its worth a shot.

Comment: Okay Tim, let me try that and let you know..thanks

Comment: Sorry Tim, still not working :(

Comment: `file:///` is considered "insecure" as of Android 4.0. Chances are your code will actually work on a device running Android 2.3 or lower... however, it apparently no longer works as of Ice Cream Sandwich. I was never able to figure out a working alternative :/

Comment: Have you ever tried to `loadUrl` after `setWebViewClient`? It's a good practice usually! Let me now about it...

Comment: You need to loadUrl last. Also "some text" has to match your url.

Comment: yugidroid, I do add the loadUrl after setWebViewClient but it still does not work :( Help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

## Try to get the `Real Path` of the file first and then try as your way like this:

---

```
String YourURI="/android_asset/myfile/file.html";
YourURI = new File(getRealPathFromURI(YourURI));

//Got the Real Path Of the File

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null); 
  cursor.moveToFirst(); 
  int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
  return cursor.getString(idx); 
}

webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl(YourURI);                      //**Used the Real Path**
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("some text")){
            setDialog("some fancy text");
        }
}
```

---

## If the File is in the SDCARD :-

---

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
  Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
} 
else 
{
  webview.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                   +"/android_asset/myfile/file.html");
}
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("some text")){
            setDialog("some fancy text");
        }
}
```

---

## Final Edit:-  This Code Works Perfectly for Asset Folder

---

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
        WebView webview;  
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile/file.html");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Haresh, could you provide a solid example for me please?

Comment: Haresh I get File can not be resolved to a type error, I cant progress,please advise

Comment: Is the file located in the SDCARD?? If so then try the latest edit of my Answer

Comment: No Haresh, it is stored in the assets folder as I showed in the code, I just need to find a way of parsing the contents in the android assets folder and then use the loadUrl method..any ideas? Thanks for all the help

Comment: Please Check my Final Edit.You can try this creating a new Project for trail.

Comment: Haresh, I am sorry for not being clear, I can access the files in the assets folder but can not access the url links in those files so I can not use shouldOverrideUrlLoading method..this is where I am stuck..

Answer (score 1):

There is another way that would also work for you---

```
webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

where custromHtml is the HTML line that is used to be displayed.

on the place of "custromHtml" you just pass "file://android_asset/myfile/file.html".

I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

You may try for this too -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String myURL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        myBrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

        /*By default Javascript is turned off,
         * it can be enabled by this line.
         */
        myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myBrowser.loadUrl(myURL);

    }
```

*and also check you have placed the file in correct folder of main project. If all this is ok, make a clean project and fix project. Then try to run it.*

Comment: Thanks Kumar, I have followed your advice but I can not get shouldOverrideUrlLoading to point to the dialog I want to show..this is so frustrating, it can not access the html file in the assets folder

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String myURL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        myBrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
        myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myBrowser.loadUrl(myURL);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work well try it-----

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]"

Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.androidbook.samplevideo/raw/myvideo");
```

This link is also useful -

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

[Loading an Android Resource into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855008/loading-an-android-resource-into-a-webview)

Answer (score 0):

shouldOverrideUrlLoading does not work on ICS for file://, but works for fine for external urls.  loadURL works fine loading from the assets folder.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    web.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
    //web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    web.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

.....

```
class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("MyWebClient", "url is: " + url);

        if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("google.com")){
            Log.d("MyWebClient","url is: " + url);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this forum solution which solved the problem for me: http://www.cynosurex.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Java/Android/Android_4_has_a_.file....android_asset.webkit.._bug

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this ....

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl("file://android_asset/myfile/file.html");
webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("some text")){
            setDialog("some fancy text");
        }
```

Comment: It should be `file:///`, not `file://`.