# Load other android package resource from webview?

Tags: android, webview, uri, android-resources

From this post: [Loading an Android Resource into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855008/loading-an-android-resource-into-a-webview)

I tried `Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+galleryPackageName+"/"+info.icon);`

then in webview: `<img src="android.resource://com.android.gallery3d/2130838158">`

but I got `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

if same package I can use `file:///android_asset/xxx`

but how can I load from different packages?

Comment: What is your galleryPackageName?

Comment: com.android.gallery3d, just android built-in gallery app, you can see the result is `android.resource://com.android.gallery3d/2130838158`